# Retrieve row values by matching 2 columns SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a similar table as follows. The `id` is for all the employees in the company. `Manager_id` will match with several ids in the `id` column.

```
id       employee    manager_id
1         Jane          5
2         Bob           5
3         Anna          1
4         Rosa          6
5         Dylan         5
6         Theo          5
```

I would like to somehow perform `id` matching with the `manager_id` to the `id` column to retrieve the manager name. I'm not sure what would be the approach or function to use in this case, so I'm not sure what to research? If you could please give me any suggestions, I would really appreciate.

```
id       employee     manager
1         Jane         Dylan
2         Bob          Dylan
3         Anna         Jane
4         Rosa         Theo
5         Dylan        Dylan
6         Theo         Dylan
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  Or a correlated subquery.  What have you tried?

Comment: I am quite new to SQL so I don't know the exact approach yet. Thank you for your hint - I guess I can do a SELF JOIN, right?

Comment: Yes. self join will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use left outer join to get the manager's name along with the emloyee name.

```
select e.id,e.employee, manager.employee from 
employees e left join outer join employees m on e.manager_id=m.id
```

Comment: thank you so much for the suggestion, however, the join for some reason did not work for me - most of the rows came back being empty

Comment: In your data does every row from employee table has manager_id? If not then this query will select only id and employee column with null as manager.